# i want to create a 24/7 tv broadcast with youtube videos

Tags: youtube, playlist, television

i would like to make a website with a 24/7 "tv broadcast" which will....in the begining at least, play youtube videos one after the other.

for now i have on joomla the HWDVIDEOSHARE which gathers all my videos and play them on a playlist in JWPLAYER, but i would like to play embeded youtube clips one after the other in their embed and not in JWPLAYER to avoid the "embeding is disabled by its owner"

is there a script that i can use or a program to take the youtube links and display them one after the other?

i wish to ask that and from there to proceed because i am looking for a direction......

thank you very much.

ronen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into the Youtube APIs?

http://www.youtube.com/dev